# What is the proper way to create a root sym link in Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I need to replicate our production environment by having a directory placed at `/reports/2019/`, and as you know this is not possible in Catalina anymore (at least without disabling the SIP.

Doing that is actually disabling the security but I guess there is a proper way to do this.

Is there a way to create a symlink like `/reports` that is linked to the read-write volume without disabling SIP or not compromising the security?

Comment: You can disable SIP, create the symlink or directory, then re-enable SIP.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add symlinks to the root filesystem by adding entries to `/etc/synthetic.conf`.

From the `synthetic.conf(5)` man page:

> **synthetic.conf** specifies a single synthetic entity per line. Each line
>        may have one or two columns, separated by a tab character. If a line has
>        a single column, it denotes a virtual empty directory to be created at `/`.
>        If a line has two columns, it denotes a symbolic link at `/` whose link
>        target is given in the second column.

So, if you had your writable directory at `/Users/myself/reports`, you could symlink it to `/reports` by doing the following:

1. `sudo vi /etc/synthetic.conf`
2. Add an entry `reports    Users/myself/reports`, where the empty space is a tab (`Ctrl-V + Tab`) character.
3. Reboot

The directory should show up after the reboot.

Comment: Excellent! The file `/etc/synthetic.conf` does not exist, so I had to create it. Everything works like a charm.

Comment: Wow, thank you for clarifying the tab character. I first tried it with a space and it caused infinite reboot loop. I had to delete synthetic.conf by booting into recovery.

Comment: I had the same issue as Matt -- the system seemed to be stuck in a boot loop because I used a space instead of a tab character in the file. In order to fix the problem, I had to (1) boot into Recovery Mode (hold CMD-R on boot-up), (2) open the Terminal (Utilities -> Terminal) (3) mount the APFS drive via `diskutil apfs unlock "Macintosh HD"`, and then (4) removed the `synthetic.conf` file from the mounted disk (5) Booted up again, and created the `synthetic.conf` with the proper tab character.

Comment: any way to do this without reboot?

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks for documenting that @eqzx

In 2021 with Big Sur, things have changed a little bit. I got the crashloop for an undefined reason. Safe mode will NOT help you. Starting in recovery, as mentioned, is possible. Apple support will not help you but tell you to repair.
Repairing the system will, beside waste your time, solve nothing.

The solution is:

- start in recovery mode (CMD+R)
- open a terminal
- you may expect to see your `synthetic.conf` under /etc or private/etc... it won't be there
- Mount the Data volumes: `diskutil apfs unlock "Macintosh HD - Data"`
- If you are curious: `diskutil info disk2s2`
- cd into the data volumes: `cd /Volumes/"Macintosh HD - Data"`
- cd `private/etc`
- from here you can remove the file with `rm synthetic.conf`

You can now reboot, create a new file, likely get stuck again :) and fix it with the same solution.

Comment: Thanks @Chevdor
I was stuck with this same issue for half a day.
This made my day today.

Comment: I'm using Big Sur and adding entries in `/etc/synthetic.conf` work for me. It appears there are some conventions that need to be followed when creating this file and populating it with entries. [These are well documented in an answer in the AskDifferent site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388240/12227). Following those instructions may prevent the crashloop from occurring. YMMV.